# ios CGPointMake error - Fatal Exception NSRangeException

Tags: ios, exception

I got this error from Crashlytics.

> Fatal Exception NSRangeException
>   *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

I looked into my code, it happens at this point as below:

```
CGPoint targetOffset = CGPointMake(currentEpisodeCellNumber * 90, 0);
```

I think if `CGPointMake(0,0)`, I got a crash. But I am not sure this is main problem. 
I cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

I added my codes

```
if (self.episodeNumber > 1) {
    sceneNumber = [[[episodesArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"scene"] intValue];
}
else {
    sceneNumber = [[[episodesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"scene"] intValue];
}   

currentEpisodeCellNumber = self.episodeNumber - sceneNumber;

CGPoint targetOffset = CGPointMake(currentEpisodeCellNumber * 90, 0);
```

I got error at this point, sceneNumber = [[[episodesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"scene"] intValue];

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same version of code that threw the exception?

Comment: Yes. i got this error both ios 6 and 7.

Comment: Code version, not iOS version. You have most likely edited the code so you're looking at the wrong line compared to the exception details...

Comment: `CGPointMake(0,0)` is valid.  That line of code cannot be causing your error.  Perhaps you should consider whether `episodesArray` might be empty at the line that says `[episodesArray objectAtIndex:0]`, since that would cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the crash you are getting from Crashlytics is not your CGPointMake function call.

The crash message is telling you that your are trying to fetch object 0 in an empty array. That's pretty clear. Your CGPointMake call does not reference any arrays. You need to look again as to the source line that's causing your crash.